# FOR XML to DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying to load a c# dataset with xml generated using SQL "FOR XML" clause. It seems like if I format the XML so that the schema is included, the data doesn't get loaded. If I leave off the schema, I get the data, but not the correct datatypes.

How can I load a DataSet from XML generated using the FOR XML clause so that both type information and data are loaded? (Some combination of FOR XML AUTO|RAW,XMLDATA|XMLSCHEMA???)

**UPDATE**

Changing it to use an XmlReader built from the string rather than a reader created from the SqlXml variable allowed both type info and data to be brought into the dataset, so long as the schema info was included in the xml. Of course, I think this means an extra parsing of the xml. Is there a better solution?

```
            string xml = cmd.Parameters["@xml"].Value.ToString();
            StringReader str = new StringReader(String.Format(@"<root>{0}</root>", xml));
            System.Xml.XmlReader xmr = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(str);
            ds.ReadXml(xmr);
```

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE prc_GetXmlData @xml XML OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('test') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE test
    CREATE TABLE test (field1 INT, field2 BIT, field3 MONEY, field4 VARCHAR(8000))

    INSERT INTO test 
        (field1, field2, field3, field4)
    VALUES
        (3, 1, 99.45, 'testvalue')

    --what combination????
    SELECT @xml = (SELECT * FROM test FOR XML RAW, XMLDATA)
END
```

c#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(<<connectionstring>>);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("prc_GetXmlData", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            }

            System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml sqlXml = (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml)cmd.Parameters["@xml"].SqlValue;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(sqlXml.CreateReader());

            for (int t = 0; t < ds.Tables.Count; t++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Column DataTypes:");
                for (int c = 0; c < ds.Tables[t].Columns.Count; c++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ds.Tables[{0}].Columns[{1}].DataType={2}", t, c, ds.Tables[t].Columns[c].DataType);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Rowcount:{0}", ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the xml string you get returned from that procedure into ReadXml(). it will populate your dataset.

```
string xml = "<your xml string>";
DataSet ds= new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(xml);
```